# Chrome API identity.getAuthToken not working in Opera browser

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, opera, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

### Introduction

So I created a small chrome extension which uses the identity.getAuthToken method to authorize the user.
When using the chrome browser everything works as expected, but when I switch  to opera the token results in undefined.

The AppId and OAuth2 are set up in the google cloud console and manifest.json, so that should not be an issue.

---

### The Code:

```
window.onload = function () {
  // Read scores from local storage to display while authentication happens and actual scores are being fetched
  chrome.storage.local.get(["scores"], (data) => {
    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0 && data.constructor === Object) {
      return;
    }
    updateScores(data.scores);
  });

  chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
    {
      interactive: true,
    },
    function (token) {
      console.log("Identity token is: " + token);
      if (token === undefined) return;

      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        { command: "token", data: token },
        (response) => retrieveScoreValues()
      );
    }
  );
};
```

The chrome.runtime.sendMessage just sends the token to the service worker.
the method retrieveScoreValues sends an API request to google sheets to fetch data from it.

To reiterate: When using the chrome browser everything works, just not when using opera.

---

### What I tried:

I tried getting the authToken via a direct api request, but that didn't work for me.
Also tried copying the token from the chrome instance (opening the extension in chrome, copying the logged token and hardcoding it for opera). That worked for a moment, until the token expired, so the fetching of the authToken is the only thing that doesn't work.

Comment: Were you able to make your extension work in Opera? What did you do?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning not yet. Haven't worked on it further though. When I do and find a way I'll update.